# Reduce jobs only when All Mappers finish?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

Good day...
I am a bit confused; what is the difference between a reduce task and a reduce job?
here is my case; I have read that reduce does not start until all mapping is finished...
but in the hadoop output I see otherwise:

```
12/02/11 10:58:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 60% reduce 16%
12/02/11 10:58:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 60% reduce 20%
12/02/11 10:58:55 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 65% reduce 20%
```

the reduce is 16% whilst the map is still 60%...
What is really happening here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are three phases of the "reduce phase": shuffle, sort, reduce. The shuffle copies the data and the sort groups the keys together. The reduce is the actual `reduce` function that you wrote.

The way the percentages work is shuffle is 33%, sort is 33%, and reduce is 33%. What you are seeing is "about 16%/33% (i.e., 48%) of the data has been copied over to the reducers". The final 33% of "reduce" can't start until all the mappers are done.

Answer (score 4):

The reducers start copying the output mappers produce, as soon as 1st mapper finishes processing its input, but reducers cannot process the input until all mappers have finished executing their tasks. The reason behind this is that the reducer might receive more input data from unfinished mappers, which can change the order it processes its input.

The percentage completed for reducer you see on console, signifies that reducers are in the process of copying data from mappers.